# Why does this GOTO not work in BASIC 256?

Tags: goto, basic, qbasic

```
2 Print "What is your name"
input nameperson$
Print "What is your Dad's name"
input ageperson$
Print "Your Name is ";nameperson$;" ";ageperson$
GOTO 2
```

Why does this code not work in BASIC 256? I have tried it in QB64 and it worked.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with VB.NET. Please don't spam tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been years since last time I programmed in BASIC, but I remembered that there were different *flavors* of the language (it was the same with C, Pascal, and others).

I googled a bit of both **QB64** and **Basic 256**: The short answer is that the BASIC flavor of **QB64** supported line numbers, but **Basic 256** implemented a newer flavor of BASIC that didn't support line numbers.

In order to use `GOTO` in **BASIC 256**, you must use labels (any identifier followed by a colon ":")

```
thisIsALabel: Print "What is your name" 
input nameperson$ 
Print "What is your Dad's name" 
input ageperson$ 
Print "Your Name is ";nameperson$;" ";ageperson$ 
GOTO thisIsALabel
```

Comment: "It's been years since last time I programmed in BASIC, but I remembered that there where differemnt flavors of the language" ...different flavors is quiet an euphemism. There has been a chaotic diversity, to an extend that "BASIC" and "BASIC" now do only match by chance.

Comment: It is likely, but not definite, that the original problem could have been corrected by just putting a colon after the line number, e.g., `2: Print "What is your name"`